# wtforms & flask: populate RadioField

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

i have a form with several `RadioFields`:

```
from wtforms import Form, RadioField

class AnswerForm(Form):  # type: ignore

    answer = RadioField(
        "Answer",
        choices=(
            ("A", "yes"),
            ("B", "don't care"),
            ("C", "no"),
        ),
    )
```

if i run that in a POST request,i can populate the form with the data from `request.post`:

```
AnswerForm(
        formdata=request.form,
        prefix="3",
 )
```

`request.form` contains:

```
{"3-answer": "B"}
```

and that works fine.

but i may want to fill the values from a dictionary (e.g. from the database - especially in a GET request) and maybe merge that with `request.from` (which is immutable). i tried this:

```
form_data = dict(request.form)
# update form_data with values from db

AnswerForm(
        # formdata=request.form,
        data=from_data,
        prefix="3",
    )
```

but that does not work: the form is empty - no item is selected anymore.

what am i doing wrong? how can i fill the `AnswerForm` with values from the database (and maybe even merge them with values from `request.form`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best i came up with so far is this:

```
request_form = request.form.copy()
request_form.add("3-answer", "B")
AnswerForm(
    formdata=request_form,
    prefix="3",
)
```

but i guess there re better ways to do that...